# Error in x y.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression, prediction

When I'm running the lm model with a data frame of 65461 entries, I get residuals back for 65354 entries. Therefore, I get the following error while running a plot:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

The code I used:

```
lm_model109 <- lm(mydata$Volume ~ (mydata$1+ mydata$2+ mydata$3+mydata$4+mydata$5)*mydata$6*log(mydata$7)*log(mydata$8)) 
residuals_lm109 <- resid(lm_model109)

plot(mydata$5,residuals_lm109)
```

Comment: Probably your data has missing values that are dropped by `lm` and omitted from the residuals. Maybe try `na.omit(mydata)$5` (though if your data has missing values in columns not included in the model that still might not work...)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yesterday, we deleted exactly 107 observations of the dataset. How is it possible that now exaclty 107 observations are dropped by lm?

Comment: Maybe you marked them missing rather than deleting them. Or maybe it's a coincidence. Show more code, share some data, if you need more help than wild guesses.